# Castlevania Lords of Shadow last boss

Tags: castlevania-lords-of-shadow

When i'm fighting the last boss of Lords of Shadow there are times that the boss is disabled and you can go with your magic powers in the circles that are around him.
So in this situation when i reach the boss his health point is disabled and i cant do any damage to him.
what i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I read this [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/castlevania-lords-of-shadow/Walkthrough_(Chapter_Twelve))

> Satan can use both Shadow Magic and Light Magic, and the crux of the battle revolves around your own ability to use those same attacks. Don't worry about your magic meters, as they will never decrease, meaning that you have an unlimited amount of magic to use in the fight. And this magic is the key, since you'll need to attack Satan with the opposite magic he's currently invoking in order to have any hope of actually damaging him. Dont bother using standard attacks as they will never damage him. When the staff he wields glows red, it means he has Shadow Magic engaged, so use Light Magic attacks with your Combat Cross to start to damage him. Likewise, if his staff glows blue, he's using Light Magic, at which point you'll want to invoke Shadow Magic to eliminate him

Based on this I am guessing that you probably hit him with standard attacks or with the same type of magic.

EDIT:
When he's stunned, you can initiate quicktime events to damage him and ultimately finish him off, but remember to navigate the runes that surround him once stunned using your own magic, or you'll never get to him in one piece.

Comment: this is about when he is fighting back or when he is disabled and that red and blue circles are around him? I understand the way to reach him,but in every possible scenario his HP is locked,like there is a transparent gray box on it.

Comment: Edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: thank you but as i said in the question i can pass the runes and reach him,but in this situation his Hp is locked.why his HP is locked?

Comment: As i said in the answer u have to initiate a quicktime event.

Comment: i tried again and after he stunned i reached him and waited for anything to appear on the screen to initiate the quicktime event  but nothing happened. i was in the last circle just beside him and his HP was locked and grey.nothing more like the circle which appeared during the game